# TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined Jest

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

i'm using react-testing-library and jest in my project. 
I'm newbie on this. i tried to make some test on my component but i'm getting error. I understand i need to pass props to test which of using my component but i can't figure out how.

It's my main component:

ComponentA.tsx:

```
export const ComponentA: FC = () => {
    const [active, setActiveItem] = useState("");

    return (
            <div className="right-menu">
              <ComponentB onMouseEnter={() => setActiveItem("componentB")} />
            </div>
    );
  });
```

here is ComponentB.tsx:

```
export const ComponentB: FC<CompProps> = ({ onMouseEnter }) => {
  return (
    <div onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}>
      <img src={icon} alt="Some Image". data-testid="comp-b" />
    </div>
  );
};
```

and here is my CompProps which i'm using on my componentB:

```
type CompProps = {
  onMouseEnter?: () => void;
};
```

so here is i wan't to test my ComponentB: 
it's my test file for ComponentB:

```
import React from "react";
import { ComponentB as Component } from "./";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

it("renders without crashing", async () => {
  const wrapper = render(
      <Component onMouseEnter={() => {}} />
  );
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  wrapper.unmount();
});
```

and here showing error : **TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefinedJest**

what's this mean and how figure out with this?

Comment: Can you include the complete traceback?

Comment: const wrapper: RenderResult<typeof import("/Users/...../node_modules/@testing-library/dom/types/queries")>
TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefinedJest

Comment: Is that the full traceback? It's missing line and file information and is suspiciously short.

Comment: then i don't know where get it

Comment: error showing on this line:   const wrapper = render(

Comment: The error is being caused by something within that function. Without a traceback there's no way for me to evaluate what that in a timely manner.

Comment: Sorry but i don't have more details. Anyway thank you for help

Comment: @ciz30 Did you find a solution to this? If yes, can you please share it as an answer here? Otherwise this thread is a bit useless..